# bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)

Tags: gluon, gluon-mobile

I'm using Mac 10.11, IntelliJ, JDK 1.8. I created a default multi-view project from the Gluon selection in the IntelliJ create new project. I tried to create an apk using the Tasks -> Other -> android task. I get the following error:

```
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileRetrolambdaMain UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:compileAndroidJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileRetrolambdaAndroid SKIPPED
:compileEmbeddedJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileRetrolambdaEmbedded SKIPPED
:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileRetrolambdaTest SKIPPED
:compileRetrolambda UP-TO-DATE
:mergeClassesIntoJar
:validateManifest
:collectMultiDexComponents
:shrinkMultiDexComponents
:createMainDexList
[ant:java] Java Result: 1
:dex FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':dex'.
> UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception parsing classes
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:752)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:718)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1200(Main.java:85)
    at         com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$FileBytesConsumer.processFileBytes(Main.java:1645)
    at     com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
    at     com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:672)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:569)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMultiDex(Main.java:366)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:275)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
  Caused by: com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic     (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.parseClass(Main.java:764)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1500(Main.java:85)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$ClassParserTask.call(Main.java:1684)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:749)
    ... 12 more
  1 error; aborting

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 10.939 secs
bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.parseClass(Main.java:764)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1500(Main.java:85)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$ClassParserTask.call(Main.java:1684)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:749)
    ... 12 more
1 error; aborting`
```

Any ideas how I might figure out what the issue is?

Thanks

Comment: I deleted the project and the android sdk directory. Re-installed android sdk and recreated project. Now I get: PARSE ERROR:
unsupported class file version 52.0
...while parsing com/gluonapplication/BuildConfig.class
1 error; aborting

Comment: You are probably using external dependencies that are compiled with jdk 8. This not supported android, and requires a tool like retrolambda to be applied the classes. We've just updated the jfxmobile plugin to apply this on external dependencies as well. Can you update the top of your build.gradle file (which is located at the root of your project) to use version 1.0.10-SNAPSHOT of the jfxmobile plugin? You'll also need to add the following line in the repositories section of the buildscript: maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/' }